# Why does Grand Central Dispatch show image in cell only upon tap?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have something funny going on.  A tableview loads flickr photos via its API.  Upon loading the view, it creates a names & photoURL arrays.  Then in the cFRAIP tableview method it uses them to set the cells values.

I decided to play around with GCD and ended up with this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell Identifier"] autorelease];

cell.textLabel.text = [photoNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


dispatch_async(kfetchQueue, ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[photoURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

});



return cell;}
```

But what i get is a tableview with the photo names in each cell without a picture.  The pictures only load when I tap on the cell.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

[Manipulations to your application’s user interface must occur on the main thread.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW147)

```
dispatch_async(kfetchQueue, ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[photoURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok but can you explain why it works that way that until I tap on it the image is shown?

Comment: BTW, for some reason the code above doesnt work.  It throws off my cFRAIP method enclosure.  I get an Expected ')' at the closing '});'

Comment: Sorry, typo, just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see, you had a small typo:

```
dispatch_async(kfetchQueue, ^{
    //NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[photoURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });    //<-------right here :)  thx!
});
```

---

However, the result is still the same.  Its displaying the images only when i touch them.  I think its because thats when its queued to fetch the NSData.  I would have to load the photos in an init method instead of in the cFRAIP method.

Comment: it needed cell setNeedsLayout :)